# Share internet connection

Tags: network-manager, internet, internet-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sharing Wireless Connection with Other PCs and Phones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171914/sharing-wireless-connection-with-other-pcs-and-phones)

My system has 2 network cards, one wired and one wireless.
I've a local cable net connected to my ethernet card.

Now I want to share my internet connection using wireless.

I tried this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60980/how-to-share-an-internet-connection-via-wifi), but, it did not worked for me.

Comment: Hi Ravish, I made a very detailed answer to your question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/171914/how-do-i-share-my-laptops-internet-connection-with-my-android-phone/174027#174027 how you like it.