# How to share wireless Internet with Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, internet, sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share a wired internet connection via Wifi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60980/how-to-share-a-wired-internet-connection-via-wifi)

I have a PC which connects to the Internet via wifi. However, my ISP only allows one PC to connect to the Internet at the same time.

Also, I have a wireless router, so I want to connect this router to my laptop and share my Internet connection via this router.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: it's documented on the ubuntu documentation wiki here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router ... if you run in to an issue while working through the guide edit to ask that specific question and i'll see if i can get you passed it.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy. You connect to the wireless network as normal. Then select the wired network connection, and in the IPv4 settings, select "Method: Shared with other computers".

Now your wireless connection will be shared on the wired one. Connect your router, and it will share it with other computers in your network.