# Wireless Internet connection sharing

Tags: internet-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share a wired internet connection via Wifi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60980/how-to-share-a-wired-internet-connection-via-wifi)

Is there a way to connect my desktop PC to my laptop to acess the web? I have wifi and don't have a wireless card, so my desktop is unconnected, and I really don't want to drag it all over my house to the router just to install some software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On your laptop, search for Network Connections.
2. On the wired tab, select the connection and click "edit"
3. Go to the IPv4 settings tab, and change the method to "Shared to other computers"
4. Save all changes, and if appropriate, unplug and reconnect the ethernet cable between your PC and laptop

Comment: When I attach the ethernet cable, the laptop disconnects from wireless and tries to connect via the cable, and the desktop stays unconnected. I am running Kubuntu 11.10 32 bit and Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, respectively.

Comment: Try going back to the IPv4 menu, Click "routes" and select the option that says "only use this connection for resources on its network"

Comment: That option is grayed out.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to drag it downstairs if this is all you guys have to offer.