# I need a wifi Hotspot application

Tags: wireless, android, adhoc

I need a WiFi hotspot application  like Connectify!
I have a Samsung Galaxy S II and it doesn't find ad-hoc access point

What can I do?

Comment: To those who voted to close this question as 'off topic': please explain me why.

Comment: Are you asking for an adroid app or an Ubuntu app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to share an internet connection via Wifi?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60980/how-to-share-an-internet-connection-via-wifi)

Comment: If you're asking for an Android app, you might ask over on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need a wifi chip that supports host mode for that. Sadly most of them don't. If you can verify that yours supports host mode take a look into `hostapd`. There are several tutorials available.

As alternative there are some apps in the play store that claim to be able to connect to ad-hoc networks. Those need at last android 4 and root access. A lot of people are having problems with this but it may be worth a try if you haven't tried already.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on the Networking indicator.
2. Choose "Create new wireless network" (or something similar, on my Ubuntu's it's translated to my language)
3. Type in wireless name/password.

Note that such network will have access to the Internet only if your Ubuntu is connected to it via other means (e.g. wire), for a single wi-fi antenna cannot work as hotspot while being used to connect to some other network.