# How can I create a Wifi Hotspot like in Connectify?

Tags: hot-spot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share a wired internet connection via Wifi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60980/how-to-share-a-wired-internet-connection-via-wifi)

When I had Windows 7 I used Connectify (http://www.connectify.me) to create a Wifi Hotspot. Now I have a wireless connection on my netbook to browse the web and I want to share that wireless connection with my Android smartphone. I only have the wireless connection **(I don't have a wired connection)** on my netbook. How can I share it? I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Please note that the OP doesn't have a wired Internet connection to share.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **System Settings**, under **Hardware** chose **Network** and on the left side chose **Wireless** you will see the **Use as Hotspot** on the bottom of the window.

Comment: When I click on **Use as Hotspot** it appears a message who says that I have to disconnect from my actual wireless connection (WLAN_XXXX) and create a new Hotspot. When I create the new Hotspot  Ubuntu connects to the new Hotspot and disconnects from WLAN_XXXX and I haven't got Internet on my netbook (and I neither can't share it, of course).

Comment: In a conventional way you can't create a hotspot with a wireless network. Connectify does some workaround to bypass that restriction