# Share internet via WiFi like Connectify in Windows

Tags: wireless, hot-spot

I use [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) in Windows to access Internet via WiFi and create a WiFi hot-spot to share Internet with my other devices.

Since Connectify isn't available for Ubuntu, are there any ways that I can gain the same functionality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup a wi-fi hotspot (access point mode)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode) OR follow [here for in Adhoc-mode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60980/how-to-share-a-wired-internet-connection-via-wifi) (Adhoc won't support andriod/ios devices)

Comment: @Web-E When using as a wi-fi hotspot, the used Wi-Fi can't be used to connect to other network via WiFi for internet access, So, it's not duplicate.

Comment: In your question you should have mentioned you are using single device to connect. :). Regarding to your question, That support is very minimal in ubuntu. It is an architectural support of windows 7, even without connectify [you can do so](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3849841). However related ubuntu thread is here - [How do I create a WiFi hotspot sharing wireless internet connection (single adapter)?](http://askubuntu.com/q/318973)