# Hotspot and Internet access together -- why not?

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, network-manager, hot-spot

If I go *Settings → Network → Wireless* and select *Use as Hotspot...*, I get the following message:

> If you have a connection to the Internet other than wireless, you can use it to share your internet connection with others.
>
> Switching on the wireless hotspot will disconnect you from ABC.
>
> It is not possible to access the internet through your wireless while the hotspot is active.

What are the technical reasons why I can't set up an Hotspot and be connected to the Internet at the same time?

Comment: Cross-posted on U&L site: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84440/hotspot-and-internet-access-together-why-not

Answer (score 4):

You're basically after turning your PC into a **WiFi repeater.**

If you use **Ubuntu,** you can use `create_ap` to create a hotspot:

```
sudo create_ap wlan0 wlan0 SomeNetwork SomePassword
```

Where the first interface is the device you want to use for the hotspot, and the second interface is the one that has access to the internet. Since you're repeating over the same adapter in your case, use the same interface.

If you use **Windows,** you can use [Connectify Me](https://www.connectify.me/) or any similar software to use the same adapter that connects to the internet to run a hotspot.

Comment: Unless a WiFi adapter has two radios I don't think it can be in two modes at the same time. Are you sure that it is possible what you're describing in Windows?

Comment: Ah, cool. With some more thorough searching I found this for Linux: [Connect to multiple AP with one Wifi adapter under Linux/FreeBSD?](http://serverfault.com/q/192144/135437)

Comment: OMG! I have been looking for this days, Thank you

Comment: Mh... I asked this on AskUbuntu because I was seeking an Ubuntu-related answer :-)

Comment: @user16538 Of course! That's why I'm commenting, not providing an answer yet. The Q&A I linked to just states that it is possible for Linux+FreeBSD and shows examples for FreeBSD. So we need the same but for Ubuntu here.