# How to share Internet on ubuntu to android

Tags: wireless, networking, android

I have seen searched a lot about sharing internet of computer to Android device (when the computer is connected to the internet via wi-fi not lan- Ethernet)

here are some of the links that helped me, But I have not got a way to figure out the way.

I have also tried out reverse-tethering via usb but it seems to be working only if I am connected via Ethernet not over wi-fi

My computer has single wi-fi card

[link1](http://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/),[link2](http://pastebin.com/L7cZ3a0u)

[image: more details]

can I create a hot spot or share internet via any means to my android phone

Comment: solution to your problem lies here [How do I create a WiFi hotspot sharing wireless internet connection (single adapter)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap)

Comment: yes seems it is the question I am looking for bad that google did not help me with this

Comment: ty for helping out with it

Answer (score 0):

How to share internet to other devices through wifi:

---

I'll suggest you the method that worked for me and my friends.
install kde-nm-connection manager. [details on how to install & setup](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/share-internet-with-android-ubuntu-1404/)

This should work. If not do as follows:

- disable the wifi driver from "Additional Drivers" in System Settings (skip to last step if there are no wifi drivers shown already)
- restart you computer
- now we will be installing a [non-free firmware wifi driver](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware-nonfree). copy paste this command and restart you computer: `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree` After installing this you can try to setup the hotspot again.

Comment: I question was not about problem with wifi, I was asking how to share internet over when my computer is connected to internet via wifi

Comment: @dhanvi how to setup wifi hotspot ? this link: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/share-internet-with-android-ubuntu-1404/

Comment: No what my question is how to share internet with android when I am on wifi, this can be done in windows using virtual router or connetify @edward torvalds

Comment: @dhanvi I dont think you can use internet via wifi and share internet via wifi at same time. are you sure ? let me check it on windows

Comment: yes I am sure @edward torvalds [virtual router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) also [connetify-me](http://www.connectify.me/) both of them can do it in windows

Comment: @dhanvi give me time to investigate. it may take some time coz i have exams now. i will find the answer to it and show it to u :)

Comment: btw edward torvalds also see the two links that I have mentioned in the question they might help you, I wish there exists an application like virtual router to linux :)