# Share laptop's internet connection

Tags: 14.04, internet, sharing

My laptop runs 14.04. It receives connection through WiFi. However, I have a couple of Windows laptop in vicinity which requires internet connection. Is there any way that my laptop acts as server to provide internet connection via ethernet or wifi to other laptops ?

Comment: I prefer to use it as a internet server. Also, mine is not a wired network, it is wireless.

Comment: I was expecting something simple. The answer in the suggested link is way above my head.

Comment: I am just wondering why you want suck a setup? Can't you connect the other device directly to the WiFi network?

Comment: The duplicate thread is for Wi-Fi. 

I get that it seemed a bit too comprehensive. One of those answers links to this article, maybe that's simpler to perform? http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/

Comment: if you have another network card, you could use that, set up a "NAT" environment and use the machine as a router...

Comment: @JonasStumphStevnsvig I am trying to have a setup that receive via Wireless adapter and share via ethernet adapter.

Comment: Check out this answer too: http://askubuntu.com/a/609199/44179

Comment: @user227495 that was exactly was I thought. effectively you would be using your laptop as a router  duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/3063/share-wireless-connection-with-wired-ethernet-port

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have a laptop which gets internet via WiFi and wishes to share the internet to other PCs via a different network. You want your laptop to act as the connection between the two networks.

In other words, you want to make your laptop, which has an internet connection to act as a gateway on a separate network that you create and connect all other devices to it. [Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Internet_sharing) is the guide I followed. The documentation is for arch linux, but it will work on Ubuntu too. [Here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/119147/how-do-i-route-traffic-from-wifi-hotspot-to-usb/120280#120280) is an answer in another SE site that applies this idea.

But it is to be noted that a WiFi card can't connect to two different networks simultaneously. So if the the connection to the network from which you get internet is via WiFi, the second network you create should be via Ethernet.

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try. I am having a office setup where I cannot give WiFi password to the laptop users.