# Creating a WiFi hotspot in Xubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: xubuntu, internet, hot-spot

I am new to Xubuntu and I would like to know if I could setup a WiFi hotspot from a Wifi connection?
How can I realize that?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap (the UI in xfce seems to be very similar)