# Wifi hotspot on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: wireless, 19.04

How can I make my Ubuntu PC a Wifi Hotspot? I appreciate any helps.

Edit: It is wifi-connected to the internet.

Comment: 0nly hotspot? how is net connected? Ethernet USB Dongle etc?

Comment: Check Ubuntu documentation for more details: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html.en

Answer (score 0):

```
nmcli device wifi hotspot con-name <Name of interface> ssid <NameOfYourHotspot> band bg password <YourPassword>
```

It requires network-manager installed and being connected via ethernet.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer? What are `con-name`, `yourname`, etc.?

Comment: Hi, I establish a wifi-connection. What should I do in that case?

Comment: You mean that you are connected via Wifi, and want to create another hotspot (Acces point) transmitting again Wifi signal ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do

Comment: I haven´t tried it yet, but try this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap

Comment: have you got a the same with WPA2?