# How to set Ubuntu 18.04 laptop as wifi router from command line?

Tags: command-line, 18.04

It might be simple, but can anyone tell me how to set my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop as a wifi router from command line?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can have a look here. It should work fine. https://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap/324785#324785

Comment: @CuriousCoder Thank you for the link.