# trying to use my desktop to put out a wifi signal other devices can connect to

Tags: wireless

I could do this simply with Windows and using a program called Virtual Router. With Ubuntu I am not sure if this is possible. I have a desktop that is hard wired to the wall and gets its online connection from there. I also have a wireless card installed and working. I would like to be able to share the connection to be online from the wired connection with other devices. Please help, thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to share a wired internet connection via Wifi?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60980/how-to-share-a-wired-internet-connection-via-wifi)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Connect & Share your Internet Connection (Wired & Wireless)](http://askubuntu.com/q/171914/65926)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a very simple method using just [networkmanager](https://jeremy.visser.name/2009/03/simple-internet-connection-sharing-with-networkmanager/), the default network configuration tool (I'm not at a Ubuntu machine atm, so I can't check if this still applies).

If you need more advanced connection sharing, probably all information you need for this can be found on the Wiki page on [Router](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router) setup. In order for Wireless to work as described on that page, your card either needs to support [master mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode), work in an [Ad-Hoc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Adhoc) network or connect to an already existing wireless access point.

If this is not enough information, keywords that might help you search relevant guides on the net are "masquerading", "network address translation", "NAT".

Comment: networkmanager starts adhoc with wep.

Answer (score 0):

Use `networkmanager` from network menu for one-time connections or `hostapd` with config at /etc/ for permanent access point.

Networkmanager setups adhoc, wep, dhcp and nat by few clicks.
With hostapd you need to make it all by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search via google and turned up a number of hits, follow the link below.

https://www.google.com/search?q=turn+linux+into+wifi+router&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

The prevailing method seems to be to set up an 'as hoc' network, but the security isn't good (from reading the posts).

I suspect that a better way would be to set up you PC as a full dhcp server, but I haven't found any links for using the WiFi card as part of it. It could be this is automatic and hence no further details are required! I'll keep searching and post a link... When I find one.

OK found the following on the Ubuntu wiki.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessAccessPoint
Note that it uses a PC with 2 WiFi cards, this is because it needs one to communicate to the main network (this would be equivalent to your wired connection), and the other is used to relay data to other devices.

Follow the tutorial, and see how you go. If you get stuck post a new question. In this iinstance you may find that the Ubuntu forums are more effective than ask, make decent notes on your setup, and you can even add in your full solution here as an answer and accept that as the solution.

David